# Can't render equation of latex in org-mode

Tags: emacs, latex, org-mode

I tried using c-c c-x c-l, org-toggle-latex-fragment. It said image is created and a little black box shows up with no equation.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxboy.png)

Comment: this could mean your latex isn't setup right, or is incomplete. What are the details of your latex installation, and  are you doing this in windows?

Comment: @JohnKitchin wow, I was just watching your video can trying to add equations to my org files. And the video is just amazing. Anyway, here is the log, can you take a look can tell me want's wrong? https://gist.github.com/danielyang1009/3609c98fb3403f46da9a

Comment: and yes, it's in windows. I have no problem when I using my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On windows I have had to do this in the past to get latex fragment images to work:

```
(setq temporary-file-directory (expand-file-name "~/../Local/Temp"))
```

for some people.